# Javascript regex to match all power calculations in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

So StackOverflow already helped me getting this far by optimizing my regex to match power calculations in a string:

```
var regex = /[0-9]+\^[0-9]+/;
```

At this point it only matches the first one in the string, but I want it to return all the power calculations within that string using:

```
str.match(regex);
```

Comment: replace `/[0-9]+\^[0-9]+/` with `/[0-9]+\^[0-9]+/g`. The `g` at the end makes it global

Answer (score 6):

Add `/g` modifier to your pattern to force the global match, like this:

```
/[0-9]+\^[0-9]+/g;
```

---

Still, there can be a subtle problem here. Consider this:

```
var x = '3^4^5',
    r = /[0-9]+\^[0-9]+/g;
x.match(r); // [3^4]
```

Yes, second power expr is not matched: as regex engine already covered '3^4' part, next match just won't cover `4^5`. So you probably need to augment your regex into this:

```
/[0-9]+(\^[0-9]+)+/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `g` (global modifier)

```
/regexp/g
document.write(str.match(patt1));//44^3,2^3
```